# LSTM with return_sequences - "Training a model on multiple timesteps simultaneously"

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, sequence

So I'm following Tensorflow's [LSTM/time series tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#recurrent_neural_network) and there's something I don't understand. I do understand what happens with `return_sequences` on/off, however, it is stated, that with `return_sequences` on you allow

> Training a model on multiple timesteps simultaneously

I don't quite understand what this means. If you keep it off, the input will go through all the previous timesteps, and make a prediction. Your loss will be the error of this prediction vs. the actual. You're still training on all the timesteps, right (although not simultaneously I guess?).

Now if it's on, it's making a prediction on each timestep - what's the loss in this case? Is it the average error for each prediction in the sequence? Why is it better to switch `return_sequences` on, as it's done in the tutorial? Does the model learn more or faster in this case? How does it impact the learning?

It is also stated that

> With `return_sequences=True` the model can be trained on 24h of data at a time.

Isn't that still the case with `return_sequences=False`? In the example they're still teaching the model to predict 1 timestep based on the previous 24.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `return_sequences` to `True` or `False` depends entirely on which one is appropriate with respect to how you are going to make predictions at inference time:

- If you want your model to make a prediction only when it has consumed a whole sequence as input, then you use `return_sequences=False`, so that your loss is only based on the output after ingesting the whole sequence.
- If you want your model to be able to make predictions after any number of timesteps, you set `return_sequences=True` and set the loss over all the time step outputs. As we are dealing with time series, the appropriate loss could be the average squared error over all time step outputs.

About the statement "With `return_sequences=True` the model can be trained on 24h of data at a time", I think it means that you are training the model for each of the 24h time steps, instead of the single prediction trained with `return_sequences=false`.

Comment: What if during training I want the loss to be based in the last step only, but during inference I am interested in knowing the probability at each step? Is that possible?